# Questions when using Streams with input from Linux pipes

Tags: dart, rxdart

Following questions as a beginner to *Dart* and RxDart. The versions of Dart and that of RxDart are latest as of yesterday.

In the following example Dart program, saved in file 't.dart', only one of the two options, A or B, is un-commented at a time. Before executing it a '*fifo*' is created by executing '*mkfifo fifo*'. The results of the execution are as below.

***Questions***:

1. Why does a *Stream* opened using File show only one byte received, whereas when using *stdin* *Stream* and input from the same *fifo* sees all the input?
2. Why does the *RxDart* operator *take* emits only one value?

**Option-A**: Executed as '*dart t.dart*' in one window, and '*(for i in A B C D; do echo -n $i; sleep 1; done) > fifo*' another window in same directory. The output is:

```
byte count: 1, bytes: A
File is now closed.
```

**Option-B**: Executed as '*cat fifo | dart t.dart*' in one window, and '*(for i in A B C D; do echo -n $i; sleep 1; done) > fifo*'. The output is:

```
byte count: 1, bytes: A
byte count: 1, bytes: B
byte count: 1, bytes: C
byte count: 1, bytes: D
File is now closed.
```

---

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

main(List<String> args) {

  // Option-A
  // Stream<List<int>> inputStream = File("fifo").openRead();

  // Option-B
  // Stream<List<int>> inputStream = stdin;

  inputStream
    .transform(utf8.decoder)
    .take(16)
    .listen((bytes) => print('byte count: ${bytes.length}, bytes: ${bytes}'),
        onDone: () { print('File is now closed.'); },
        onError: (e) { print(e.toString()); }
      );
}
```

Comment: What is your process for Option A? Do you run the second script and wait for it to complete before executing the dart script or are you running both simultaneously?

Comment: For option A I start the dart program first, which waits. Then I start the echo, only then does the Dart program outputs as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

*(I'm not knowledgeable enough in the internals of how Dart I/O works to give a firm answer, so this is my best guess as to what is happening.)*

What it seems is going on is that in Option A, you are creating a stream to a yet-to-exist file. Dart sees that the file doesn't yet exist, so publishing to the stream is delayed. Then when you run the echo script, it creates the file and appends the first value to it "A", after which you tell it to sleep for 1 second.

During that second, Dart sees that the file now exists and begins streaming data from it. It reads "A", and then it reaches the end of the file. As far as Dart is concerned, that's the end of the story, so it closes the stream. By the time the script adds the "B", "C", and "D" to the file, Dart has already finished executing the program and exited the process.

In Option B, rather than telling Dart to stream from a file, you are tapping into the process's input stream which (as far as I am aware) is going to remain open for as long as there is stuff being written to it. I have a feeling that understanding what is exactly happening requires better knowledge of `cat` and how piping works in the terminal than I possess, but I believe the long-story-short of it is that the `cat` program knows that the file is being written to which prevents it from terminating early. As such, whenever `cat` gets new data, it pipes that data to the Dart process's input stream.

Back to the Dart code, you are listening to the input stream which is still expecting data since `cat` is still executing, and as such hasn't closed. Only when the file writing process is complete does `cat` recognized that it has reached the true end of the file and shuts down, at which point Dart recognizes that it isn't going to get more data and so closes the input stream.

*(As I said, this is merely my best guess, but I suspect that an easy way to tell would be to look at the times your Dart script and other script are finishing. If in Option A the Dart finishes long before the script does and in Option B they finish at roughly the same time, that would be sufficient evidence to me to indicate the above is indeed what is happening.)*

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response. In option-A I did try to start the echo first, but the outcome is same as before - just one character makes it. The hypothesis I have, and which I need to in/validate is I am using the 'bleeding' version of RxDart. I will check and post the findings. At least I don't seem to have made an obvious mistake in using RxDart.

Comment: @Cap I can't imagine the issue would be coming from RxDart. You don't seem to be importing RxDart, for one, and for another the `transform`, `take`, and `listen` methods are all vanilla Dart `Stream` methods. RxDart wouldn't be messing with any of that.

Comment: Agree that RxDart isn't needed, so I downloaded the Dart version to 2.6.1 from 2.7.2. The behavior is still the same. Not sure if it makes sense to downgrade the Dart version to an earlier version.

Comment: @Cap I don't think this has anything to do with a Dart version or an RxDart version and it's just the default behavior of the `File.openRead` stream. Is there any particular reason you need Option A to work like Option B?

Comment: At start I only had option-A, and was puzzled by the behavior. So I attempted option-B it with compare behavior of stdin. The capability is simple enough, and getting it to work will likely mean exploring and understanding the other functionality around it... a learning opportunity as well.

Comment: When I attempted to use TCP sockets (server or client), I find the behavior as desired / expected as in case of stdio. Why using a Linux named pipe fails still eludes me, as does the case where I use a pair of pts terminals (created using 'socat pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0'). May be something special about Linux device files... which should work as I believe.